# How to install Beamer in Windows XP using LyX

Tags: installing, lyx, miktex, windows

I installed LyX on Windows XP, but when I attempt to load a file which uses beamer it says MikTeX does not have it! What to do?

> (I have MikteX 2.7)

I am trying to update MikTeX, but when searching and trying to install `beamer` I get this error:

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> MiKTeX 2.7 is not supported any more. Visit http://miktex.org/2.7/ for details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MikTeX 2.7 is no longer supported and you should install MikTeX 2.8 or later in order to install new packages through the MikTeX Package Manager (which is the program that lets you install automatically).

If you do not want to download all your installed packages again (for example, if you have a somewhat full installation), there is a tutorial to import your installed packages [here](http://www.miktex.org/2.9/setup). You just need to replace

`mpm --admin --verbose --repository="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.8" --import-all`

with

`mpm --admin --verbose --repository="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.7" --import-all`

or wherever you have MikTeX installed.

If you don't want to do this or don't know how, you can just uninstall MikTeX 2.7 and install MikTeX 2.9. However, this may take a long time.

Comment: I installed with Lyx all missing packages "Tools->Reconfigure" install all mising, that fixed it all.